# Why is it giving me this syntax error? I’m following a tutorial. (Beginner)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, syntax, syntax-error

It's saying there's a syntax error (seems simple enough) but I've double-checked the video (and my brain). I don't see why it would be saying that.

Been following this tutorial and taking notes to a T (if I need to include more code let me know).

I defined "run_test" and am entering the parameters in question. Help?

[image: python_project_error]

Comment: Please post your code and errors as text.  Not as an image.

Comment: to answer your question,  you're missing a ```)``` at the end of the ```print``` line

Comment: @deadshot that would be the poster's next error :)

Comment: There is also a red underline at the missing parenthesis... look out for red underlines in your ide.

Comment: please edit your post and share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have extra opening parenthesis before ‘str(len(...))’

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!  I can’t believe it was that simple. So I have a follow-up question: why would it display a syntax error but reference line 29 instead of 27? the red '^' is pointing to line 29’s function call, is it not?

Comment: The python interpreter is expecting a closing parenthesis and goes ahead to find that in the next line where it finds `run_test(...)` which is unexpected and raises an error.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now—thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a closing brackets for str in print statement `')'` , add this and your program will work

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, you haven't defined the list of questions yet. If you have defined your list of questions it is probably a typing error in your code. If there is the full code under the tutorial you are doing then i would compare my code to the code from the tutorial.